# How to force caption below figure

Tags: floats, captions, positioning

I find captions appearing above figures in the PDF output of a latex thesis file using the code below:

```
\includegraphics{chapter2/fig5.pdf} 
\begin{figure}  
\label{Fig. 5} 
\caption{Time responses using optimal drive sweep rates obtained from a numerical      
parameter search for the: (a) pendulum $(\omega=1, \alpha=-0.01)$, (b) softening
Duffing oscillator $(\epsilon=1/6, \omega=1, \alpha=-0.001)$ and (c) softening  
Duffing-Van der Pol oscillator $(\epsilon=1/6, \omega=1, \mu=0.005, \alpha=-0.01
$) using the  downward swept drive $(F \cos(\omega t-0.5(\alpha t^2)), F=0.5) $ }
\end{figure}
```

I presume the problem has to do with the lengthy caption.  I read a similar question on this site but unfortunately the answer did not work. I also tried adding [!h] after the includegraphics command to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put the `\includegraphics` command immediately *after* `\begin{figure}`. Also, put `\label` after `\caption` for correct cross-references. Positioning arguments like `[!ht]` should, if it all, be used this way: `\begin{figure}[!ht]`.

EDIT: To clarify: In your document, the caption is inside a (floating) `figure` environment, while the graphic presumably is part of the normal text flow. Therefore, it is likely that the caption will be placed above (or even separate from) the graphic.

Comment: Hi lockstep, Thank you for the solution and explanation. It works great! Best wishes,

Comment: +1, but `\label` after `\caption` wasn't necessary for me. I got errors.

Comment: This doesn't work.
\begin{figure}[!ht]\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Pics/lbp_num_points_radii}
  \caption{Slika 2.1: LBP atributi.}
%  \centering  
  \label{fig:lbpfeaturecalculationprocess} 
\end{figure}

Doesn't change a thing, i have tried putting the includegraphics in a newline still nothing